# How do I ignore these data migration errors (Class does not exist but mentioned)

Tags: magento2

Using the Magento Data Migration tool, I get the following errors:

```
[2018-09-07 20:57:11][ERROR]: Class ugiftcert/source_template does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=556
[2018-09-07 20:57:11][ERROR]: Class ugiftcert/source_template does not exist but mentioned in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_id=557
[2018-09-07 20:57:11][ERROR]: Class ugiftcert/product_pdf does not exist but mentioned in: catalog_eav_attribute.frontend_input_renderer for attribute_id=584
[2018-09-07 20:57:11][ERROR]: Class ugiftcert/product_conditions does not exist but mentioned in: catalog_eav_attribute.frontend_input_renderer for attribute_id=585
[2018-09-07 20:57:11][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: Error occurred. Rollback.
[2018-09-07 20:57:11][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: EAV Step: rollback
[2018-09-07 20:57:11][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: Please fix errors and run Migration Tool again

[Migration\Exception]
 Volume Check failed
```

I understand I can ignore the attributes with xml files. But I don't understand the syntax. I believe I need to add these in the ignore group in `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist`

I'm looking for answer on how to add the above errors to these ignore files. Something like:

```
<group name="ignore">
    <attribute type="catalog_product">msrp_enabled</attribute>
    <attribute type="catalog_product">group_price</attribute>
</group>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Went to `eav_attribute` table, looked for `attribute_id` of 556, 557, 584, 585. Found the `entity_type_id` was 4 for all those. `eav_entity_type` table says `entity_type_id` of 4 is `entity_type_code` "catalog_product". So, same as the included examples in eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist.

`eav_attribute table` lists the `attribute_code` for those IDs as `ugiftcert_email_template`, `ugiftcert_email_template_self`, `ugiftcert_pdf_settings`, `ugiftcert_conditions`.

Resulting xml:

```
<group name="ignore">
    <attribute type="catalog_product">msrp_enabled</attribute>
    <attribute type="catalog_product">group_price</attribute>
    <attribute type="catalog_product">ugiftcert_email_template</attribute>
    <attribute type="catalog_product">ugiftcert_email_template_self</attribute>
    <attribute type="catalog_product">ugiftcert_pdf_settings</attribute>
    <attribute type="catalog_product">ugiftcert_conditions</attribute>
</group>
```

Comment: I am getting :
[2019-04-10 17:50:47][ERROR]: Class Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\BaseImage does not exist but mentioned in: catalog_eav_attribute.frontend_input_renderer for attribute_id=648

but 648 id is not exist in eav_attribute and catalog_eav_attribute table.

Comment: hello @Joe, I am getting below error after migration starts 
 Notice: Undefined offset: 9 invendor\magento\data-migration-tool\src\Migration\Step\Eav\Data.php on line 292