# Magento 2: Ignore EAV tables during migration

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I am setting up a migration from 1.8.1.0 to 2.2.9. All product related data has been manually set up in the new store so I would like to ignore anything product related including all the eav tables.

The map.xml already contains entries like these (by default):

```
<ignore>
    <document>eav_attribute</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <document>eav_attribute_group</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <document>eav_attribute_set</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <document>eav_entity_attribute</document>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <document>eav_entity_type</document>
</ignore>
```

But after migration all my newly created custom eav attributes' options are gone. For clarification: these attributes only exist in the new magento 2 database.

Basically all I need is customer and order data to be migrated. That's why I put in these sections into my config.xml:

```
<steps mode="data">
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
</steps>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241379/how-do-i-ignore-these-data-migration-errors-class-does-not-exist-but-mentioned

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to transfer only selected data from Magento Data migration tool. Magento data migration tool simply transfers data from table to table. It is built in this way to support data integrity and delta data transfer. Try to follow these steps to achieve the same.

1. Install fresh Magento2.0 without sample data.
2. Use data migration tool to transfer data.
3. Now delete the product from this Magento.
4. Export products from your Magento in which you have updated catalog
5. Import your product data into this installation.

Note: If you want to use delta transfer then do not remove and add a new catalog before delta transfer.

Comment: I don't want to selectively transfer data from tables. I want to skip some tables entirely. Only customer and order data should be migrated.

Comment: It's not possible to ignore EAV tables. EAV tables also contain information about customer attributes. Best way is to transfer entire data and then delete data that you don't need.

Comment: Here comes the funny part (just found out about it): magento 2 does not use the eav tables for customers or customer addresses. All data is stored inside customer_entity and customer_address_entity. Checked it in another shop that has been running for a year now.

Comment: really! have you checked eav_attribute table? Information about customer's attributes like first name, last name , details of their backend model are kept in it.  for example search "Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Backend\Website" in backend_model field.  eav_attribute table is used by the magento to store meta data of customer and products.

Comment: customer_entity_datetime, customer_entity_decimal, customer_entity_int, customer_entity_text, customer_entity_varchar... all empty and obviously not needed. The same goes for customer_address_entity tables. The term "EAV" was misleading in this case but they belong to the EAV system.

Comment: you misunderstand this.These tables are use for keeping customer's attribute's data (apart from the attribute which are already created by magento). customer_entity_{datatype} table holds values for customer attribute for that particular datatype. eg. customer_entity_int holds value of customer's integer attribute. You have these tables empty just because you do not have any customer's attribute.

Comment: I am in the process of migrating those values from magento 1 to magento 2. In m1  all those values ARE stored in those tables whereas in m2 they are all part of the customer_entity table.

Comment: I guess the point to be made here is that m2 considers a lot of data not as attributes anymore and instead treats them as fields.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Most of the customer attributes of M1 are field in M2. But if someone creates a new attribute and add data for customers then these tables will be used.These tables are still in use in M2. My point is, eav tables stored meta data of customer, product and extension (if any extension made is such way). That is why you can not ignore eav tables while data transfer.