# Magento 1 to 2 Data Migration - EAV Step Error

Tags: error, migration, magento2.2.3, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

Updating another Magento 1 website to Magento 2 - haven't faced this issue before:

**Magento 1.9.3.4 to Magento 2.3.3**

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/XXX/public_html/XXX/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php on line 292
```

I was initially facing issues of the duplicated 'Default' entries coming over:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '182' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

But I removed these from the Magento 1 environment, fresh install of Magento 2 Database.

**Then, run command:**

```
php73 bin/magento migrate:data -r -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.4/config.xml
```

Which gives me the above error.

Looking at [Migration fails with "Notice: Undefined offset: 1"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259768/migration-fails-with-notice-undefined-offset-1) - I am using a clean install (from Softaculous) of Magento 2.

So I shouldn't face this issue when running the migration command on a clean Magento 2 database, should I?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: may be issue third party extension attribute value, so need to first remove attribute after check

Comment: @VishalBaraiya referring to a Magento 1 extension attribute or a bundled Magento 2 extension? Cheers.

Comment: m1 module attribute.

Comment: @VishalBaraiya thanks for that! I have noticed 'Product Attachments by Amasty' on the Magento 1 instance. This may be the issue - would I add this to the 'ignore'?

Comment: help to check this link => https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241379/how-do-i-ignore-these-data-migration-errors-class-does-not-exist-but-mentioned

Comment: use another link https://www.tigren.com/magento-migration-process/

Comment: another way take m1 database backup and remove those attributes after run again command.